# Angular 6 - Variable in service not updating

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app with multiple components, with a singular service injected into all of them. The service contains methods to interact with my REST backend. I am trying to make it so when a request is made using one component, it increases a count variable in the service. However, when I try to access that variable from another component, it returns it's original value.

**jwt.service.ts**

```
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class JwtService {

  requests: number;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private cookieService: CookieService
  ) {
      this.requests = 0;
    }

  createJWT(id: string) {
    const url = `/${id}/token`;
    this.requests = this.requests++;
    return this.http
      .post(environment.apiUrl + url, this.cookieService.get('token'))
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError(`createJWT id=${id}`)));
  }

  getRequests() {
    return this.requests;
  }

  verifyJWT(id: string, jwt: string) {
    ...
  }

  getActiveJWTs() {
    ...
  }

  revokeJWT(jwt: string) {
    ...
  }

  signIn(username: String, password: String) {
    ...
  }

  handleError<T>(operation = "operation", result?: T) {
    ...
  }
}
```

**certificate-authority.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

import { JwtService } from '../jwt.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-certificate-authority',
  templateUrl: './certificate-authority.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./certificate-authority.component.css']
})
export class CertificateAuthorityComponent implements OnInit {

  active: string[] = null;
  activeJWT = "";
  requests = 0;

  constructor(
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {
      interval(5000).subscribe(val => this.checkUpdate());          
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getActive();

  }

  getActive() {
    ...
  }

  revokeJWT() {
    ...
  }

  viewJWT(jwt: string) {
    this.activeJWT = jwt;
  }

  checkUpdate() {
    if (this.requests != this.jwtService.getRequests()) {
      this.requests++;
      this.getActive();
    }
  }
}
```

If I access the 'createJWT()' method x amount of times from this component, it will correctly return x at each interval. But, if I access the 'createJWT()' method from another component, as intended, the current component only ever sees the requests count as 0;

This leads me to believe that each component that jwt.service is injected into would create a new instance of jwt.service. But this doesn't seem right. The whole point of services vs components is that services can contain anything that doesn't pertain to a specific view. How can I make it so no matter what component I access 'createJWT()' from, my Certificate Authority Component will return the correct amount of requests?

Comment: This happens when the two components are in seperate NgModule and you have added the service in both the module's providers array

Comment: Are those components part of lazy loading module? If so, they will create a separate instance of service provided within some other module.

Comment: I have everything in app.module.ts - `@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CertificateAuthorityComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    JwtService,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

Comment: @RussellQuinlan, your function "checkUpdate" NOT increment the "request" property of your jwtService (just a variable request of your certifycate.authority component)

Answer (score 2):

There is only one service. But you have a **copy** of the counter in the component, so incrementing the counter of the service won't automagically increment the copy  in every component.

Also, your interval increments the value of the copy instead of initializing the value of the copy with the service value, and you don't initialize the copy at initialization time.

Just don't create a copy, and display the unique, correct value stored in the service:

```
get requests() {
  return this.jwtService.getRequests();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, where am I creating this copy?

Comment: J@Russell, B Nizet say you that, to recover the property requests of your service you use a getter. A getter make Angular refresh the value in the view each change happens

Comment: @RussellQuinlan your service has a requests field, and the component has a requests field, and they should both always have the same value, so you have a copy in the component.